# The textbox is not visible until I show the data in Angular4

Tags: angular, dom, angular-forms

I am working on angular4 web API in Visual Studio 2015. Here I have some text boxes in the page, and on clicking a button I am selecting data from database and showing it in the textbox.

I want to show empty boxes when page loading but here The textbox is not visible until I show the data (which means is, unless I gets data from server "item details" will be empty and thus in DOM textbox is not rendered, and it appears only when I gets the data) I am new in angular please help

Here is my HTML Code

```
 <form #newForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="OnSubmit(newForm.value);newForm.reset()">
     <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Item Code</label>
                        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemdetails;">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemcode" name="itemcode" [value]="item.ItemCode" required />
                        </ng-container>
                    </div>




       .........etc rows...........



   <input type="button" value="Add Item" class="btn btn-success" 
  (click)="addItems(newForm.value);newForm.reset()" /> </div>
```

This is my TS code

```
    addItems(value: any) {
this.items = new IComboDetails(value.ItemID, value.ItemCode, value.ItemDescription, value.PackingtypeID, value.PackingtypeName, value.quantity);
this.stockitems.push(this.items);   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because you are displaying input field inside *ngFor.
Unless you get details from server the **itemdetails** array remains empty and the input field is not rendered.

You can declare a **boolean flag** to check if you got data from server OR use **itemdetails.length**

```
 <div class="form-group">


      <!--Until server returns its data show empty text field may you can keep it disabled -->
      <ng-container *ngIf="!itemdetails || itemdetails.length == 0">
          <label>Item Code</label> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="temporaryField"  /> 
      </ng-container>

      <!--If server returns data display data in text field -->
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemdetails;" >
            <label>Item Code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemcode" 
            name="itemcode" [value]="item.ItemCode" required />
      </ng-container>
</div>
```

Another way :

```
 <div class="form-group">

      <!--Until server returns its data show empty text field may you can keep it disabled -->
      <ng-container *ngIf="!itemdetails || itemdetails.length == 0">
          <label>Item Code</label> 
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="temporaryField"  /> 
      </ng-container>

      <!--If server returns data display data in text field -->
      <div  *ngIf="itemdetails && itemdetails.length > 0">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemdetails;" >
              <label>Item Code</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemcode" 
               name="itemcode" [value]="item.ItemCode" required />
          </ng-container>
      </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can't have multiple template bindings on one element. Use only one attribute named 'template' or prefixed with * ("n ignore the *ngIf -->
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemdetails;" [ERROR ->]*ngIf="serverResults">

Comment: Sorry, yes that's right.
But *ngIf can be ignored with *ngFor as mentioned in above. Beause until the server responds array is empty it won't create any problem.

Just make sure you update the flag once you get serve response.

This will work

       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemcode" name="itemcode" 
      [value]="item.ItemCode" *ngIf="!serverResults" />

      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemdetails;" >
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="itemcode" 
            name="itemcode" [value]="item.ItemCode" required />
      </ng-container>

Comment: *ngIf can be ignored here cause 2 textbox can be displayed os is empty and another is with value?

Comment: what you mean by serverResults?

Comment: You need to use a boolean flag to check if you have got response from server or not.
For exmaple, I have used **serverResults** as a variable name


Or check length of the **itemdetails**  as a condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197243/discussion-between-rider-and-snehal2124).